# How to get a private value without define an other fonction getValue()?

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my function : analyserMain
It works for 2 values with only analyserMain() but when I want to had the values of "table1" (So I had only m_flop1 to begin) I have an error because m_flop1 is private ! So am I forced to declare a function in class Table : getValeur() ? I already created it in class Carte and Table contains Cartes

Thank You

in Mains.cpp :

```
void Mains::analyserMain(Table table1) const
{
// LES 2 CARTES EN MAINS (COMME FCT PRECEDENTE)
val1 = m_carte1.getValeur();
coul1 = m_carte1.getCouleur();
val2 = m_carte2.getValeur();
coul2 = m_carte2.getCouleur();  

//+ LES 3 CARTES SUR LA TABLE
val3 = table1.m_flop1.getValeur();
}
```

Comment: Simple getters and setters are usually a bad design idea, and no different from making the variable `public` in the first place. Try to model your classes around *behavior* instead of simple wrappers around a set of values. What are the classes supposed to *do*?

Comment: Can't you change `Table` and `m_flop1` to a POD types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access a private member from another class (unless it is a friend of the class). Your options are to declare a getter function or to change the accessibility of the member to public (or protected depending on the particular case).

Here you can found detailed information about accessibility in C++:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.cbclx01/cplr040.htm